# How to replace **ALL** using conditional in regex

Tags: regex

My question is, from this example of txt file, ive written a code to match from [POLYLINE] until Data0, now i want to replace(**add-because it didnt really replace anything from the following just insert them in the group**) this (RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0) into the group

```
Example 1
[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label= Old Road
RoadID=38751
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39470,102.48414)
[END]

[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=New Road
RoadID=38752
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39435,102.48413),(3.39413,102.48438)
[END]
```

Example after replace/add RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0):

```
[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label= Old Road
RoadID=38751
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39470,102.48414)
RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0
[END]

[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=New Road
RoadID=38752
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39435,102.48413),(3.39413,102.48438)
RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0
[END]
```

The tricky part is i dont want to replace(add) in line of text where theres already has RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0. I want to add them like the example above where there are no RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0

Comment: (\[POLYLINE\])(?:\r?\n(?!Type).*)*\r?\n(Type=0x6)(?:\r?\n(?!Data0).*)*\r?\n(Data0=.+)     Is the code i used to match from [POLYLINE] to Data0

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/6D8MKj/1) what you want?

Comment: oh sorry im using edit pad pro that use same flavor as java i think, well not really but close cuz it match with every group including the one that has RoadDistance, but yeah basically like that, thanks

Comment: You'll need to add the language tag to your Question though. That also include your attempted regex. Don't add clarifications in comments. Also explain how your attempted regex didn't work and what you got instead.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, was in a hurry and still new to this, 3 downvote makes me realize that haha, thanks for the heads up will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to use is:

```
(\[POLYLINE\]\n[\s\S]*?\nData0.*\n)(?!RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0)
```

1. `(` Start of capture group 1.
2. `\[POLYLINE\]\n[\s\S]*?\nData0.*\n` Matches `[POLYLINE]\n' followed by 0 or more arbitrary characters non-greedily followed by a newline followed by 'Data0' followed by 0 or more non-newline characters followed by a newline.
3. `)` End of capture group 1.
4. `(?!RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0)` A negative looaahead assertion stating that the following characters are not 'RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0'.

You want to replace the group 1 match with '$1RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0\n', which is the group 1 match followed by 'RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0\n` (how you specify the group 1 match is language dependent).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/edvWAK/1/)

In Python:

```
import re

s = """[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label= Old Road
RoadID=38751
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39470,102.48414)
[END]

[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=New Road
RoadID=38752
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39435,102.48413),(3.39413,102.48438)
[END]


[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=New Road
RoadID=38752
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39435,102.48413),(3.39413,102.48438)
RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0) already present
[END]"""

s = re.sub(r'(\[POLYLINE\]\n[\s\S]*?\nData0.*\n)(?!RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0)', r'\1RoadDistance=2,1,0,0,0)\n', s)
print(s)
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/RsICUV)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that using regex here will make the code pretty complicated. It is relatively straight forward instead to write a simple parser for this file which parses each `[POLYLINE]`...`[END]` into a dictionary/map, which would make adding any new keys (as well as checking if a key exists) pretty simple.

Sample code in python:

```
def parsePolygon(lines):
    ps = []
    p = None
    for line in lines:
        if line == "[POLYLINE]":
            p = {}
        else if line == "[END]":
            ps.append(p)
            p = None
        else:
            if p:
                k,v = line.split('=')
                p[k] = v

    for p in ps:
        p['RoadDistance'] = '2,1,0,0,0'
```